# How can I extract excel rows into a python code?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet including this data:

[excelsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0gJX.png)

also I have a python code for example the first row:

V = X("V",{-2:17, -1:-67, 0:16, 1:78, 2:67},np.array([[C],[-1]]))
V1= X("V1",{ .... and so on

I want this code to get their values from the excel sheet. How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use xlrd t read where by using for loop u can iterate over the row or cols

```
file = xlrd.open_workbook(excelpath) # Open the workbook/Excel file
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)  # 1st sheet it will consider
for n in range(sheet.nrows):
    print(sheet(n, col_posn) # do your things
```